# modify binary search to find the next bigger item than the key

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

I want to modify the famous [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) algorithm to return the index of the next bigger item instead of the key being searched.

So we have 4 cases:

1. the key is smaller than all items, return 0.
2. the key is bigger than all items, return items.length.
3. the key is found at index x, return x+1.
4. the key isn't found, return the index of the next bigger one.

e.g:

```
data = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11 };
```

- search for 0 returns 0.
- search for 11 or 12 returns 6.
- search for 5 or 6 returns 3.

  ```
  while (low <= high) {
      mid = (low + high) / 2;
      if (data[mid] < val)
          low = mid + 1;
      else if (data[mid] > val)
          high = mid - 1;
      else {
          break;
      }
  }
  ```

Currently got it working by examining low and high values.
Is there any interesting code to do so!

EDIT !!!

here is how I get it working:

```
    if (low <= high)
        found = (low + high) / 2 + 1;
    else if (low >= data.length)
        found = data.length ;
    else if (high < 0)
        found = -1;
    else
        found = low;
```

I am looking for a more elegant way!

EDIT II !!!

this code works if no duplicates.
to handle the case of duplicates we need to modify the first if condition:

```
if (low <= high)
    found = (low + high) / 2 + 1;
```

to iterate until it finds a bigger element.

Comment: You're implementing the algorithm of [`std::upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound).

Comment: "search for 4 or 5 returns 3" wrong! Search for 4 should return 2, and for 5 return 3.

Comment: @ElKamina corrected search for 5or 6 return 3!

Answer (score 10):

Here is some C code that meet's the OP's requirements for searching:

- value < first item: return 0
- value is contained in the array: return index found+1
- value is not in the array but < first item and < last item: return next largest value's index
- value >= last item: return array size

It also demonstrates 4 different types of binary searching:

- Standard Binary Search
- LessThanEqual Binary Search
- LessThanEqual or Last Binary Search
- NextLargest Binary Search

(It assumes there are no duplicates in `data`)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int BinarySearch( int key, int data[], const int len )
{
    int low  = 0;
    int high = len-1;

    while( high >= low )
    {
        int mid = low + ((high - low) / 2);

        /**/ if (data[mid] < key) low  = mid + 1;
        else if (data[mid] > key) high = mid - 1;
        else return                      mid    ;
    }
    return -1; // KEY_NOT_FOUND
}

int LessThanEqualBinSearch( int key, int data[], const int len )
{
    int min = 0;
    int max = len-1;
    // var max = data.length - 1; // Javascript, Java conversion

    while( min <= max)
    {
        int mid = min + ((max - min) / 2);

        /**/ if (data[mid] < key)  min  = mid + 1;
        else if (data[mid] > key)  max  = mid - 1;
        else   /*data[mid] = key)*/return mid    ;
    }

    if( max < 0 )
        return 0;  // key < data[0]
    else
    if( min > (len-1))
        return -1; // key >= data[len-1] // KEY_NOT_FOUND
    else
        return (min < max)
            ? min  
            : max + 1;
}

int LessThanEqualOrLastBinSearch( int key, int data[], const int len )
{
    int min = 0;
    int max = len-1;
    // var max = data.length - 1; // Javascript, Java conversion

    while( min <= max)
    {
        int mid = min + ((max - min) / 2);

        /**/ if (data[mid] < key)  min  = mid + 1;
        else if (data[mid] > key)  max  = mid - 1;
        else   /*data[mid] = key)*/return mid    ;
    }

    if( max < 0 )
        return 0;     // key < data[0]
    else
    if( min > (len-1))
        return len-1; // key >= data[len-1]
    else
        return (min < max)
            ? min  
            : max + 1;
}

int NextLargestBinSearch( int key, int data[], const int len )
{
    int low  = 0;
    int high = len-1;

    while( low <= high)
    {
        // To convert to Javascript:
        // var mid = low + ((high - low) / 2) | 0;
        int mid = low + ((high - low) / 2);

        /**/ if (data[mid] < key) low  = mid + 1;
        else if (data[mid] > key) high = mid - 1;
        else return                      mid + 1;
    }

    if( high < 0 )
        return 0;   // key < data[0]
    else
    if( low > (len-1))
        return len; // key >= data[len-1]
    else
        return (low < high)
            ? low  + 1
            : high + 1;
}

int main()
{
    int items[] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11 };
    int LENGTH  = sizeof(items) / sizeof(items[0]);

    for( int i = -1; i < 14; ++i )
        printf( "[%2d]: == %2d   <= %2d   <| %d   > %d\n", i
        , BinarySearch                ( i, items, LENGTH )
        , LessThanEqualBinSearch      ( i, items, LENGTH )
        , LessThanEqualOrLastBinSearch( i, items, LENGTH )
        , NextLargestBinSearch        ( i, items, LENGTH )
    );   

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[-1]: == -1   <=  0   <| 0   > 0
[ 0]: == -1   <=  0   <| 0   > 0
[ 1]: ==  0   <=  0   <| 0   > 1
[ 2]: == -1   <=  1   <| 1   > 1
[ 3]: ==  1   <=  1   <| 1   > 2
[ 4]: == -1   <=  2   <| 2   > 2
[ 5]: ==  2   <=  2   <| 2   > 3
[ 6]: == -1   <=  3   <| 3   > 3
[ 7]: ==  3   <=  3   <| 3   > 4
[ 8]: == -1   <=  4   <| 4   > 4
[ 9]: ==  4   <=  4   <| 4   > 5
[10]: == -1   <=  5   <| 5   > 5
[11]: ==  5   <=  5   <| 5   > 6
[12]: == -1   <= -1   <| 5   > 6
[13]: == -1   <= -1   <| 5   > 6
```

- The `1st` column is the standard binary search
- The `2nd` column is the Less Than binary search
- The `3rd` column is the Less Than Or Last binary search
- The `4th` column is the Next Largest binary search

Answer (score 3):

1. List item

here is a code that :

- returns **index** of element to be searched  **if element is present**
- returns index of next greater element if searched element is not present in array
- returns -1 if an element greater than the largest element of array is searched

```
      public static int ceilSearch(int arr[], int low, int high, int x) {
    int mid;
    if (x <= arr[low])
      return low;
    if (x > arr[high])
      return -1;

    mid = (low + high) / 2; /* low + (high - low)/2 */

    if (arr[mid] == x)
      return mid;

    else if (arr[mid] < x) {
      if (mid + 1 <= high && x <= arr[mid + 1])
        return mid + 1;
      else
        return ceilSearch(arr, mid + 1, high, x);
    } else {
      if (mid - 1 >= low && x > arr[mid - 1])
        return mid;
      else
        return ceilSearch(arr, low, mid - 1, x);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want. It returns the next bigger element.

```
public int binarySearch(int[] arr, int key) {
    int lo = 0;
    int hi = arr.length - 1;int mid = 0;
    while (lo <= hi) {
        mid = (lo + hi) / 2;
        if      (key < arr[mid]) hi = mid - 1;
        else if (key > arr[mid]) lo = mid + 1;
        else return mid;
    }
    return -Math.min(lo, hi)-2;
}


public int myBinarySearch(int[] arr, int key){
     int x = binarySearch(arr, key);
     if(x >= arr.length-1 || -x > arr.length){
         //whatever you want to return
         return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
     }
     else if(x >= 0)
          return arr[x+1] ;
     else
          return arr[-x-1];
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Triall tr = new Triall();
    int arr[] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11 }; 
    for( int i = 0; i < 13; i++ ) { 
        int n = tr.myBinarySearch( arr,i ); 
        System.out.println(i + " " + n ); 
    }
}
```

Comment: actually I want to implement my version of binary search instead of using Collections.binarySearch()

Comment: @smttsp This only works if there are no repeated items in the array.  If you have three items that are the same, and the binary search returns the first or second of these, then your approach will not return the next larger item.  After the binary search, you have to scan the array upwards to look for a different value.

Comment: I see this doesn't work. At least helps you find out something :)

Comment: This code is still broken horribly:

        int arr[] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11 };
        for( int i = 0; i < 12; ++i )
        {
            int n = myBinarySearch( arr,i );
            System.out.println( n );
        }

Comment: @Michaelangelo, you were right, it is working now. Thanks for showing my mistake

Comment: @smttsp Except that is STILL not answering the OP's question; they want the **index** returned, NOT the value in the array.

        Search: 0, returns 0
        Search: 1, returns 1
        Search: 2, returns 1
        Search: 3, returns 2